# Start regexp matching in the middle of an string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing a relatively complex expression in Java using regexps + some manual parsing. What I'm doing right now is removing what I've already parsed from the string, so I have the next thing to parse right at the beginning of the string.

I would like to change this so I have a `int pos` variable and I don't modify the string. However, neither the `Pattern` nor the `Matcher` classes seem to have something to mark the index of the first character to match. Is there any way to do it?

(I know that I can just pass `str.substring(pos)` to the `Matcher`, but I guess it's much more expensive, and complicates my code a bit, since I'm using the `start()` and `end()` methods frequently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Matcher.find(int start)](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find(int)) would be useful for you

Comment: Thanks, it's looks like it's exactly what I need. I guess I should have looked better before asking.

naikus/polygenelubricants answer is also suitable, but I don't need that much control. Thanks!

Comment: À comment if anyone has the same question: Using `find()`, the `^` character matches the beginning of the whole string, not the beginning of the search. To make sure you match the beginning of the string, use `region().lookingAt()` (explained below).

Answer (score 7):

A [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) tries to find matches on a *region*, which defaults to the entire input, but may be explicitly set to a specific subrange.

From the documentation:

> A matcher finds matches in a subset of its input called the *region*. By default, the region contains all of the matcher's input. The region can be modified via the [`region(int start, int end)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region%28int,%20int%29) method and queried via the [`regionStart`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#regionStart%28%29) and [`regionEnd`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#regionEnd%28%29) methods. The way that the region boundaries interact with some pattern constructs can be changed. See [`useAnchoringBounds`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useAnchoringBounds%28boolean%29) and [`useTransparentBounds`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useTransparentBounds%28boolean%29) for more details.

Remember that like many methods in Java library classes, the `start` index is *inclusive* but the `end` index is *exclusive*.

---

#### Snippet

Here's an example usage:

```
    String text = "012 456 890 234";
    Pattern ddd = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}");
    Matcher m = ddd.matcher(text).region(3, 12);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("[%s] [%d,%d)%n",
            m.group(),
            m.start(),
            m.end()
        );
    }
```

The above prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/hbYVh)):

```
[456] [4,7)
[890] [8,11)
```

---

#### On anchoring bounds and transparent bounds

As previously mentioned, when you specify a region, you can change the behavior of some pattern constructs depending on what you need.

An *anchoring bound* makes the boundary of the region match various [boundary matchers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) (`^`, `$`, etc).

An *opaque bound* essentially cuts off the rest of the input from lookaheads, lookbehinds, and certain boundary matching constructs. On the other hand, in *transparent* mode, they are allowed to see characters outside of the region as necessary.

By default, a `Matcher` uses both *anchoring* and *opaque* bounds. This is applicable to most subregion matching scenarios, but you can set your own combination depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Matcher.region(int start, int end)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region%28int,%20int%29)

The javadoc says:

Sets the limits of this matcher's region. The region is the part of the input sequence that will be searched to find a match. Invoking this method resets the matcher, and then sets the region to start at the index specified by the start parameter and end at the index specified by the end parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [`region()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region(int,%20int)) method is what you're looking for.  Each time you match something, you move the region's start position up to wherever that match ended.  As far as the Matcher is concerned, that's now the beginning of the input.

If you set the [`useAnchoringBounds()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useAnchoringBounds(boolean)) option, you can treat the start of the region as if it were the beginning of the text (i.e., `^` or `\A` will match there), and if you set [`useTransparentBounds()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useTransparentBounds(boolean)), lookbehinds and word boundaries will still be able too "see" the preceding text.  And you *can* use both options at once.

If you always want the next match to start precisely at the beginning of the region, you can even use [`lookingAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()) instead of [`find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())--the only good use I've ever found for that method. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is your application performance-critical enough that a str.substring(pos) would matter?  A regex is going to be multiple orders of magnitude slower than a substring, so rather than making your regex more complicated just break it up.  That would be my approach.

Answer (score 0):

`String.substring` is a constant time operation; the character data is not copied, but shared with the original string. From the JDK source code:

```
// Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
this.value = value;
this.offset = offset;
this.count = count;
}

public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
// error checking omitted
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
    new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

So there is nothing to worry about in terms of substring performance.

Comment: This is `true` about `substring` being `O(1)` time and space, but then indices will need to be renumbered to translate back to the global indices, which is a hassle and error prone.